# Zoom google maps using Input range

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-api

Hi how to zoom in or zoom out google maps using input type range?

here is my input type range

```
 <input class="form-control" id="range" type="range" min="10" max="500" value="50" step="10">
```

There is all code with google map API

https://jsfiddle.net/rpsycm3j/

Comment: Max set at 500... seems like you did not have taken a look at the maximal Google maps zoom value and other properties. Here's a good start: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var map; // Make accessible

function map__Init(){
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5, -0.2), 
    zoom: 5,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
}

function map__SetZoom() {
   map.setZoom( +this.value );
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", map__Init);
document.querySelector("#zoom").addEventListener("input", map__SetZoom);
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false"></script>
<input id="zoom" type="range" min="0" max="20" value="5" step="1">
<div id="map" style="height: 400px;"></div>
```

Comment: thank you I just add switch like this:

    switch (miles) {

        case 500:
            map.setZoom(5);
            break;

        case 400:
            map.setZoom(7);
            break;

        case 500:
            break;

        case 500:
            break;

        case 500:
            break;

        case 500:
            break;

        case 500:
            break;
    }

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to have a sane defintion of the range input element, e.g.:

```
<input class="form-control" id="range" type="range" min="5" max="15" value="10" step="1">
```

Then you can do something like that:

```
function myMap() {
  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5, -0.2), 
    zoom: 10
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);

  var range = document.getElementById("range");
  range.addEventListener("change", function() {
    map.setZoom(range.value);
  });
}
```